# rpmbuild can't find the files I unpack from source

Tags: rpm, yum, rhel, rpmbuild

I am building a custom package which for the most part has a couple of dependencies and install my own files and scripts. I have those files in a `tar` file and after attempting the build I can see those files unpacked in the `rpmbuild/BUILD` directory. However there seems to be a problem with the `%files` directive as any file within is listed as `error: File not found`. The relevant section of my `spec` file looks like this:

```
%prep
%setup

%install
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/etc/collectd/
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/usr/bin/
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/usr/bin/collectd.conf.d/
install -m 777 collectd.conf.custom %{_builddir}/%{name}-%{version}/etc/collectd/

# list files owned by the package here
%files
%defattr(-,root,root)
%config /etc/collectd.conf.custom
%config /etc/collectd.d/http.conf
%config /etc/collectd.d/csv.conf
/usr/local/bin/my-plugin.py
/usr/local/bin/my-script
```

Like I said these files unpack to `/BUILD` but the builder fails in the `%install` directive after it executes the three `mkdir` statements. I am only trying to install one of the files in the above script so I can more easily tell that it succeeded. I consistently get the following error no matter what I try:

```
+ install -m 777 collectd.conf.turbine /home/vagrant/rpmbuild/BUILD/my-package-1.1/etc/collectd/
install: cannot stat `collectd.conf.custom': No such file or directory
```

This file is in this directory as I checked using `ls` but for some reason I keep getting this error.

EDIT:

My `%.spec` file is as follows:

```
Summary: my-package Collectd
Name: my-package-collectd
Version: 1.1
Release: Public
Group: Applications/System
License: Public
Requires: collectd
BuildArch: noarch
BuildRoot: %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}
Source: %{name}-%{version}.tar.gz

%prep
%setup

%install
rm -rf %{buildroot}
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/etc/collectd/
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/etc/collectd/collectd.conf.d/
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/usr/bin/

install -m 777  %{_builddir}/%{name}-%{version}/etc/collectd/collectd.conf.custom %{buildroot}/etc/collectd/
install -m 777  %{_builddir}/%{name}-%{version}/etc/collectd/collectd.conf.d/csv.conf %{buildroot}/etc/collectd/collectd.conf.d/
install -m 777  %{_builddir}/%{name}-%{version}/etc/collectd/collectd.conf.d/http.conf %{buildroot}/etc/collectd/collectd.conf.d/

# list files owned by the package here
%files
%defattr(-,root,root)
%config /etc/collectd.conf.my-package
%config /etc/collectd.d/http.conf
%config /etc/collectd.d/csv.conf
/usr/local/bin/cloudhealth.py
/usr/local/bin/my-package-collectd
```

Comment: What directory is `collectd.conf.custom` in? The working directory of the `%install` snippet? The `BUILD` directory *under* the working directory of the `%install` snippet? You need to copy files from the working directory of the `%install` snippet *into* the `%{buildroot}` at the correct locations. The `%files` section paths are *under* `%{buildroot}`.

Comment: Also why do you create `%{buildroot}/etc/collectd/` but then try to install into `%{_builddir}/%{name}-%{version}/etc/collectd/`?

Comment: `collectd.conf.custom` is in the source directory, and is unpacked to `BUILD` during the `%prep` directive. My understanding is I need to move this file in to `BUILDROOT`. If I change to `install -m 777  %{_builddir}/%{name}-%{version}/etc/collectd/collectd.conf.turbine %{buildroot}/etc/collectd/` this happens, and then I get an error `error: File not found: /home/vagrant/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/turbine-collectd-1.1-Public.x86_64/etc/collectd.conf.turbine` which is also confusing because I specify `noarch` in the spec, but `BUILDROOT` always contains `x86_64`

Comment: Can you show the whole spec file? And I think you could benefit from adding `pwd` and `ls -R` to the `%install` scriptlet and seeing where it is running from and what files you have locally already. You can then write the correct commands to install those files *into* the correct locations under `%{buildroot}` so that `%files` can find them.

Comment: I added the `spec` file in its entirety.

Comment: I just noticed some errors that may fix my problem.

Comment: Just FYI: If you are building for RHEL/CentOS 6+ then you don't need (and don't want) the `BuildRoot:` line nor do you want the `rm -rf $%{buildroot}` line at that point.

Comment: So I think your original comment was what was needed and I had to fix a few grammatical errors, but I did get the package to build, and a preliminary test confirms the files installed on the system. This package will actually end up on some servers which are running an older version of CentOS so it may be a good thing I ended up with those lines in the file (which I only added in my flailing about for a solution).

Comment: The only parts of an RPM that matter to the installing system are the packaged files and the `%pre` script, `%post` script, and `%trigger`s. Everything else in the spec file is for the RPM building system. So if you are *building* on a RHEL 6+ system you don't want or need those lines.

Comment: got it, thanks for all your help

Comment: The basic problem of this post was handled by changing the install directives. If you want to make an official answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2):

The way building an RPM works is that the `%prep` section (and often just the `%setup` macro) unpacks any source files into the build directory.

Then the `%build` section performs any compilation, etc. in the build directory and produces the built/output files.

Then the `%install` section copies the appropriate files from the build directory into their "final" locations under the `%{buildroot}`.

Then the `%files` section paths are matched against the files in the `%{buildroot}` and packaged into the RPM.

The `%install` section in your spec file is not doing that correctly.